# Saving a video to Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, video

I am trying to save a video to core data but it is not working. When I added a break point it stopped on `NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfUrl:self.videoURL];` What should I do to solve this.

Here is the code I am using to save the video:

```
- (void) saveVideo {

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    TimeTravelFeed *timeTravelFeed = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"TimeTravelFeed" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfUrl:self.videoURL];

    [timeTravelFeed setValue:videoData forKey:@"videoData"];

    NSError *error = nil;

    if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

}
```

Here is the error:

```
+[NSData dataWithContentsOfUrl:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x3b2947f4
2013-12-08 12:31:57.078 App Name[203:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSData dataWithContentsOfUrl:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x3b2947f4'
```

Comment: You probably don't want to encode the entire video file into Core Data. You should probably only save the file url to it instead.

Comment: I just wonder why `[NSData dataWithContentsOfUrl:...]` compiled at all.

Comment: Definitely don't save it to Core Data. Data over 100KB should not be stored in Core Data.

Comment: What about allowing external storage? @runmad

Comment: Save it to `NSTemporaryDirectory()`. If you save it to the documents directory it will be backed up, so you risk the user deleting the app if you take up too much storage. One caveat with `NSTemporaryDirectory()` is that the OS may purge this directory at any time, so you have to be able to re-download this movie file. Of course, if the movie is created/saved by the user you have to store in the documents directory so it's backed up and not risking removal by the OS.

Comment: CoreData is perfectly capable of saving video data with external storage enabled.

Answer (score 2):

Your error is due to the fact that dataWithContentsOfUrl: is not a method of NSData, dataWithContentsOfURL: (capital R and L) is.

More importantly though is the fact that you shouldn't be saving the entire video into Core Data, you should save the video file to disk and store the file URL to Core Data instead.